# Python: append last word from lines in input file to to end of lines of output file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, formatting, append

I have daily temperature files which I'd like to combine into one yearly file.
e.g. Input files

```
 Day_1.dat              
 Toronto  -22.5     
 Montreal -10.6  

 Day_2.dat            
 Toronto  -15.5  
 Montreal  -1.5  

 Day_3.dat      
 Toronto   -5.5
 Montreal  10.6
```

desired output file

```
Toronto  -22.5 -15.5 -5.5  
Montreal -10.6  -1.5 10.6
```

This is the code I've written for this section of the program so far:

```
    #Open files for reading (input) and appending (output)
    readFileObj = gzip.open(readfilename, 'r') #call built in utility to unzip file for    reading
    appFileObj = open(outFileName, 'a')
      for line in readfileobj:
        fileString = readFileObj.read(line.split()[-1]+'\n') # read last 'word' of each line
        outval = "" + str(float(filestring) +"\n" #buffer with a space and then signal end of line
        appFileObj.write(outval) #this is where I need formatting help to append outval
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the iteration over [`fileinput.input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) allows us to iterate over all the files, fetching one line at a time. Now we split each line at white-space, and then using the city name as the key we store the corresponding temperature(or whatever value is that) inside the list.

```
import fileinput
d = {}
for line in fileinput.input(['Day_1.dat', 'Day_2.dat', 'Day_3.dat']):
    city, temp = line.split()
    d.setdefault(city, []).append(temp)
```

Now `d` contains:

```
{'Toronto': ['-22.5', '-15.5', '-5.5'],
 'Montreal': ['-10.6', '-1.5', '10.6']}
```

Now, we can simply iterate over this dictionary and write the data to the output file.

```
with open('output_file', 'w') as f:
    for city, values in d.items():
       f.write('{} {}\n'.format(city, ' '.join(values)))
```

**Output:**

```
$ cat output_file 
Toronto -22.5 -15.5 -5.5
Montreal -10.6 -1.5 10.6
```

---

Note that dictionaries don't have any particular order. So, the output here could have been `Montreal` first and then `Toronto`. In case that order is important then you need to use `collections.OrderedDict`.

---

**Working version of your code**:

```
d = {}
#Considering you've a list of all `gzip` files to be opened.
for readfilename in filenames:  
    #populate the dictionary by collecting data from each file
    with gzip.open(readfilename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            city, temp = line.split()
            d.setdefault(city, []).append(temp)

#Now write to the output file
with open(outFileName, 'w') as f:
    for city, values in d.items():
       f.write('{} {}\n'.format(city, ' '.join(values)))
```

Comment: I'm new here and didn't know about the accept the answer function. I do have another question about the collections.OrderedDict. But I'll try and figure it out. Thanks again